# Request Headers are being converted to upper case

Tags: tomcat, https, request-headers, pingfederate, pingaccess

We are using PingAccess Gateway to protect an application that has been configured as a Site. Authentication works fine, but the request headers are not being recognized by the end application. On checking the request header names, we are able to see that the first character has been converted to uppercase.

Is it possible to restrict the header names to be in lowercase.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by "request header names" you mean the HTTP header names that you've used to map your identity attributes into (using Identity Mappings?).

This should be taking whatever casing you've input into the PingAccess administration console (Settings > Identity Mappings > (your app's associated mapping name)). Ensure the Header Name value's casing is as you want it, and the PingAccess Gateway should set it accordingly at runtime.

The casing/name of the header can be completely independent of the claims sent over from PingFederate during the OpenID Connect login.